# Can't connect raspberrypi 2 with pc using ssh

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ssh

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I have a raspberrypi 2.Firstly, I download raspbian-jessie [Raspbian Jessie](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).Then I download my OS on an sd-card following these instructions [Installing operating system images on Linux](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md)
After that I edited the file interfaces located in /path/to/sdcard/etc/network
and I added these instructions:

```
 auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.8
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.254
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

in ubuntu I try to configure a network to communicate a pc with raspberrypi :

```
System settings/network/
```

Then I created a new connection, in the IPV4 settings I chosed Manual method then I added :

```
192.168.1.8 for the raspberrypi
192.168.1.7 for the pc
```

the I put the sd-card on the raspberrypi and I plug the usb cable to the pc added to that ethernet cable after.After waiting some time I run this command:

```
ssh pi@192.168.8
```

But when I put such a password:raspberry I got:

```
permission denied,please try again.
```

What password should I enter to it and How can I know the password of ssh?

Comment: If you login to the shell and run "sudo login" can you login with userid/password pair you are trying (eg. pi/raspberry).  What happens if you try "ssh -l pi 192.168.18"?

Comment: `ssh pi@192.168.8` -- typo? Should be `ssh pi@192.168.1.8`

Answer (score 1):

SSH is no longer enabled by default. Have you enabled it using sudo raspi-config ?  Or you can place a file called ssh in the boot directory.

Answer (score 0):

Default raspbian account:

username: `pi`
password: `raspberry`

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md

It is strongly recommended to reset this password as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have local access to the server (Pi). Run your SSH connection in verbose mode:

`ssh -v pi@192.168.1.8`

Enter your password `raspberry` when prompted.

Check the server logs on the Pi for failed login attempts:

`cat /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd.*Invalid'` (you can also grep for just `sshd`)

You should find a pointer towards your next step in there, depending on what exactly is logged.